# Test coverage from SWIG-compiled C++/Python code

Tags: python, c++, swig, test-coverage

I have a classical SWIG setup where a bunch of C++ function are called from Python. Now, after adding some tests (in Python), I'd like to get test coverage on the C++ sources. The classical Python method is

```
nosetests --with-coverage --cover-package=mypackage
```

but that only works for native Python modules. In fact, this will return the coverage on the `mypackage.py` file generated by SWIG.

Since I need coverage on the C++ files (/the shared library generated by SWIG), adding `--coverage` to compile and linker flags is certainly called for. Not sure where to go from there though.

Any hints?

Comment: Just curious. Usually, you would have a library, sometimes without source code. Wouldn't it make more sense to test this library and think of test coverage for the library rather than the wrapper. Next, using `nosetests` can then be used to return the coverage of the wrapper.

Comment: I could perhaps build the library and write tests in C++ to get the coverage from that. This'll be a lot more tedious though since I don't have certain key tools available there that I do have in Python.

Comment: You could also make covering test with the only purpose of testing semantics and error handling. Next, use python for validating against a reference implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Faced with a similar issue, but with C code. It's not related to the SWIG part, just need to compile your C++ code with the coverage instrumentation and execute it. I used `gcov` and `gcovr` for that.

With `gcov`, to make this work, compile the code with the following flags (enables gcov instrumentation)

> CFLAGS_VAL += -O0 --coverage

Then, execute the test. Following the test run, .gcno and .gcda files should be generated.

To create the coverage report, run from your root folder

> gcovr -r . --filter="" --html --html-details -o coverage/coverage.html

GCOV docs, [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Gcov.html)

Same can create with lcov, follow an example in this [wiki](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Development/Lcov) page