# How to generate code coverage report for SWIG-compiled C code executed by pytest

Tags: python, c, python-2.7, swig

Using SWIG 2.0 to execute C code from python testing framework, pytest in my case.

Is there a way to configure SWIG to generate code coverage reports of the executed C code? some integration with [bullseye](http://www.bullseye.com/), [gcov](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Gcov-Intro.html#Gcov-Intro) or other similar tools?

Tried to look on the web and in SWIG documentation. Didn't find any useful resources. If there are any, please point me.

Comment: I think that you should test C layer in isolation if this is your C code. If is third party them they should have tested their code. I'm not aware of any integration between gcov and pytest :/

Comment: Related if not the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086957/test-coverage-from-swig-compiled-c-python-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually compiled the code with `gcov` instrumentation and used `gcovr` to generate the coverage report. All worked fine.

To make this work, compile the code with the following flags (enables gcov instrumentation)

```
CFLAGS_VAL += -O0 --coverage
```

Then, execute the test, `.gcno` and `.gcda` files should be generated.

To create the report, run

```
gcovr -r . --filter="<src path>" --html --html-details -o coverage/coverage.html
```

GCOV docs, [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Gcov.html)

Same can create with lcov, follow an example in this [wiki](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Development/Lcov) page